# How to invoke my AWS API Gateway REST API in my iOS / Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I created a Single View Application [in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html), and then I followed the AWS Amplify iOS SDK guide to insert authentication using my existing Cognito User Pool. Worked beautifully.

Then, using AWS Amplify, I [added a REST API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api) to allow my iOS app to access a pre-existing DynamoDB table via an Amplify-generated API Gateway and a Lambda function. I had to re-wire everything, however, to use my pre-existing Cognito User Pool, because Amplify CLI unexpectedly created a new User Pool linked to the REST API it created.

I'm getting the following error when trying to invoke my API, and no matter what I do I cannot make it go away:

```
Optional("{\"message\":\"Authorization header requires \'Credential\' parameter. 
Authorization header requires \'Signature\' parameter. Authorization header requires 
\'SignedHeaders\' parameter. 
Authorization=abJarWQiOiJyR0NiTHFsbVwvbWdGeXgzcVA1YmNRaV...
403
```

**UPDATE 5**
For more gory details, please see my [Amplify AWS iOS SDK issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1233). :)

**UPDATE 4**
This update takes precedence over my earlier updates because it now seems clear—as the error above suggests—that I am not properly calling my REST API via the authenticated Cognito user of my iOS app. I noticed that Amplify created a User Pool with *two* App Clients, one for Web access and one for mobile access. My pre-existing User Pool only had one App Client tailored for Web access. So I created a new App Client for mobile access, with an App Client Secret.

Unfortunately, I get the same exact error. So I'm wondering if something else needs to be re-wired; or perhaps I have a token issue. As I mentioned in the comment down below, maybe I shouldn't be using an OIDC token as specified in the REST API guide? Maybe I should use [AWS Credentials](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#managing-security-tokens)? **END UPDATE 4**

My API has one resource `/items` and I have an `ANY` and an `OPTIONS` method. The `ANY` method does not have any URL Query String Parameters specified for the Method Request. But it does have `RequestSchema` specified of type `application/json` for the Request Body.

My API invocation function is exactly that [specified in the AWS Amplify iOS SDK for the REST API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api#iam-authorization) (I followed their instructions for invoking my API Gateway endpoint with Cognito User Pools authorizer), except that I changed `httpMethodName` from `POST` to `GET` because POST caused a crash. Here's what it looks like:

```
func doInvokeAPI(token:String) {
        // change the method name, or path or the query string parameters here as desired
        let httpMethodName = "GET"
        // the guid is the partition key for the DynamoDB table
        let URLString = "/items/178dc797-4e3d-5bc4-815f-a280536fcd3a"
        //let queryStringParameters = ["key1":"{value1}"]
        let headerParameters = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": token
        ]

        //let httpBody = "{ \n  " +
        //    "\"key1\":\"value1\", \n  " +
        //    "\"key2\":\"value2\", \n  " +
        //    "\"key3\":\"value3\"\n}"


        // Construct the request object
        let apiRequest = AWSAPIGatewayRequest(httpMethod: httpMethodName,
                                              urlString: URLString,
                                              queryParameters: nil,
                                              headerParameters: headerParameters,
                                              httpBody: nil)

...
...
        invocationClient.invoke(apiRequest).continueWith { (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Error occurred: \(error)")
                // Handle error here
                return nil
            }

            // Handle successful result here
            let result = task.result!
            let responseString = String(data: result.responseData!, encoding: .utf8)

            print(responseString as Any)
            print(result.statusCode)

            return nil
        }
    }
```

The error given above is printed by that `print(responseString)`.

My DynamoDB table is expecting: a partition key of `userId`. A Guid String.

I'm pretty sure all I want to pass the API is a single `userId` so that the API can retrieve all items associated with it. No need for my sort key.

Is there a problem with how I am making this GET request via the API Gateway REST API?

**UPDATE 1**
There are two JavaScript files associated with my Lambda function: `index.js` and `app.js`, created by Amplify.

`index.js` is very short:

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
};
```

And `app.js` consists in some set up (first screenshot) and then a series of methods for `get`, `put`, `post`, `delete`. I'm just including two screenshots for the `get` methods -- subject of this question).

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Here's what I see when I click the Integration Request for the `ANY` method of my API. Note that I do not have a drop-down for the Mapping Template.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
But I do have a `Prod` stage that Amplify created. But I still don't see a Mapping Template anywhere in sight.

[image]

Comment: I need to see your Lambda Function and API Gateway Scheme, Screenshots will work

Comment: Thanks @excitedmicrobe. I didn't realize I was even making it to the Lambda function. I just added details re. the Lambda function. As for the API Gateway "Scheme".. do you mean schema or scheme? I'm unclear...

Comment: Oh sorry the API GATEWAY mapping template

Comment: No worries! I've just spent some time looking at the [AWS docs for the Mapping Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html). Is the Mapping Template something that I can see via the AWS API Gateway console for my REST API? The closest I've found to something looking like (but not exactly like) the template is in the local CloudFormation template for the API. ?

Comment: Mapping template for your API Gateway, here’s step 1 on how to view them: [step 1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awscomputeblogmedia/4_API-gateway-browse-to-integration-request.png) and step two: [step 2 image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awscomputeblogmedia/5_API-gateway-open-mapping-templates.png) and post what you see

Comment: Ah. I see. I was looking in the right place.. but I can not see a Mapping Template drop-down. I just updated my post with the screenshot. I really appreciate your insight here!

Comment: I appreciate that. You have been VERY helpful... leading me to a place I should be looking. I don't know why AWS Amplify did not generate a Mapping Template for this REST API. I'm going to do a bit more research into API Gateway and will keep your offer in mind. Thanks!!

Comment: Your mapping template sends out query parameters to your lambda function. Without this no parameters will be passed therefore it fails

Comment: Takes time to master a single page of the book. But I do recommend using API gateway & Lambda for an API. Using URLSESSION on swift. You can do anything around it from authentication to dynamo writing. Once again I’m really sorry I can’t foresee your situation. But I wish you good luck

Comment: @excitedmicrobe.. just remembered that Amplify created a Prod stage for this REST API. I still don't see a Mapping Template, however. Updated my post above.

Comment: You are missing a few parameters in the headerParameters which are required by the AWS to invoke a request. I used to manually sign the request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that. I overloaded the doInvokeAPI() function as described in the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api#cognito-user-pools-authorization) and presumed I was good on that account, but the error does seem to require more.

Comment: @SachinVas, yes, the auth type for my API Method Request is `AWS_IAM`. I'm [pretty sure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) that needs to be `COGNITO_USER_POOLS`. Looks like I need to create a new Authorizer for this API. I will give this a go.

Comment: Well, I'm still getting the same error as above after changing my API auth type to my Cognito User Pool. I'm sure that was the right step to take, however... I just need to look at some of these other settings.

Comment: @motivus Can you debug the request using Charles debugger. I think there you can see the actual request and figure out a solution.

Comment: I have this feeling my problem lay in the token I am passing to the API Gateway. I think I should be using AWS Credentials and not an OIDC token. But I'm not sure. Either way, Charles (or Fiddler) could definitely help me understand what's going on behind the scenes. I will get Charles installed!

Answer (score 1):

`"/items/{userId}"` is just a String. Try `"/items/\(userId)"`

Sorry, I don't have enough points to post a comment.

Comment: `userId` in my case is a Guid and it is a String. So the above treats `userId` as an Integer literal. Nonetheless, I appreciate the help!

Comment: In Swift, `{userId}` will not be replaced with the `userId` variable. Your URLString is literally `/items/{userId}`. I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to do. To use String interpolation, you need to use `\(userId)`. Then your URLString will be `/items/whateverIsInTheUserIdVariable`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. That is not my code... I'm just representing the guid that way for this post. In other words, there's a real guid there. I updated the code so this is more clear...

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. You had stated the error message was coming from the print statement, so I just assumed it was your code. I hope you get this solved. I remember the first time I worked with Cognito and API Gateway. It was a not a smooth experience.

Comment: Thanks Don. My bad. You were definitely helpful because I should not have left that mnemonic in my code snippet. I'm going to upvote the negative vote you got, if I can.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.